# Returning updated fields in PostgreSQL update query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Let's say I have a situation where two possible clients might be making the same update query on a row and I want to know which client actually won in order to prevent a race condition/the same action happening multiple times.

Is there a way an `UPDATE` query can return the fields that were actually  change during that operation?

For example, if I have the following query where row with id `8728` has the field `has_payment_method=false`:

```
UPDATE organizations set has_payment_method = true where id = 8728;
```

That query would return the fields `has_payment_method=true`

And if I run that query again, it would return no fields (because no fields were updated).

Is this even possible?

Comment: Yes, the clause is called `RETURNING`.

Comment: `RETURNING has_payment_method` always  returns the field regardless if that field has actually changed. I only want it to return if the field value changed.

Comment: "*it would return no fields because no fields were updated*" - this is a wrong assumption. The column will **always** be updated. The only way to not update something is by filtering the row through the `where` clause

Comment: Ok, I guess that's what I wanted to know. Thanks.